# Type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, desktop-application

> System.TypeInitializationException
> HResult=0x80131534
> Message=The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.
> Source=
> StackTrace:

> Inner Exception 1:
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

> eInner Exception 2:
> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

To resolve this issue, I tried the following steps:

1.Ensure that the Crystal Reports runtime is installed on the machine where the application is running.
2.Verify that the required assemblies are correctly referenced in your project.
3.Check if the application is targeting the correct version of the .NET Framework and the Crystal Reports runtime.
4.Try re-installing the Crystal Reports runtime or repairing the existing installation.
5. If none of the above steps work, you can try updating or reinstalling the .NET Framework on the machine where the application is running.